# The class will be _____ in English. How can I say this from the situation below

Tags: single-word-requests

I am Korean. I want to open a cooking class, but everyone in the class should speak English. I want to make this simple one sentence, in the form

> The class will be _____ in English.

What is the customary way of saying this?

Comment: "The class will be _conducted_ in English. This may be enough to let potential participants know that you'll be speaking English and they should expect to be able to communicate in English also.

Comment: Or "*taught* in English".

Comment: Just drop the underscore. "*The class will be in English*" .

Comment: Or "_given_ in English".

Comment: All of the above plus "...held in English."

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments by @Xanne, @AndyT, and others, there are number of acceptable options.

> The class will be conducted in Italian, and you are expected to participate entirely in Italian.

^ http://italian.rutgers.edu/undergraduate-program/courses/166-italian-250

> The class will be conducted in Portuguese.

^ https://catalog.upenn.edu/undergraduate/courses/prtg/prtg.pdf

> The seminar will be conducted in French.

^ http://french.yale.edu/academics/graduate-program/graduate-seminars

> Please note that the seminar will be taught in French.

^ http://registrar.test.fas.harvard.edu/courses-exams/courses-instruction/freshman-seminars-and-house-seminars

> The course will be conducted in Spanish and taught by Mario Vargas Llosa, the 2010 Program in Latin American Studies Distinguished Visitor.

^ https://registrar.princeton.edu/course-offerings/course_details.xml?courseid=004382&term=1112

> The course will be taught in French; papers can be written in French or English, but coursework must be done in French to count as a departmental.

^ https://registrar.princeton.edu/course-offerings/course_details.xml?courseid=002906&term=1154

"Held" or "given" could also be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you're looking for is "taught", which is a past-tense word for "teach" but can be used in a future-reference type of way, like this.

So basically, "The class will be taught in English."

Comment: The OP's context is broader than the language used by the teacher. Students are expected to communicate in the same language as well.